# React warning React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency when the deps are []

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to clean up the warnings in my DOM, and for every `useEffect` where the deps are `[]` I get an error that says useEffect has a missing dependency.  I want to trigger the effect when the component mounts, and I was under the impression that this was the way to do it. If thats the case, why the warning?

Here is the simple code im using

```
useEffect(() => {
   setDispContext("NEW");
}, []);
```

Warning is `React warning React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setDispContext'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that you use unside useEffect must be inside the dependency array, so the right way would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setDispContext("NEW");
}, [setDispContext]);
```

But sometimes you just need the useEffect to run once. If setDispContext won´t be change it can be put inside a useCallback. Otherwise the only waty would be to use :

```
useEffect(() => {
   setDispContext("NEW");
}, []);// eslint-disable-line
```

So the eslint warning won´t show.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setDispContext("NEW");
// eslint-disable-line
}, []);
```

Comment: needed to go after the closing bracket

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.